# RegSvr32 not making registry entries for COM object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, com, atl, regsvr32

I have a newly created ATL simple object in an existing ATL COM project. 
Now, registering this DLL using regsvr32 works OK. I get a message saying DLL registration was successful. But, it fails to make entries under HKCR. I can see entries for all other objects but for this one.

I am using VS2012 Professional to compile my project and the configuration type is x64. 
** I have recently upgraded my solution from VS2005 to VS2012 and this is my first object under the newly created solution. **

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Turn UAC on. Does regsvr32 display a UAC prompt? If not, it would mean that the registration was virtualized, and the entries are actually somewhere in HKCU.

Comment: @Medinoc: UAC is on. I am running cmd.exe as an Administrator and then running regsvr32 using absolute path: C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe DLLName.dll

Comment: have you checked under Wow6432Node ?

Comment: Lots of possible explanations.  Diagnose this by first looking at what keys are *actually* being written.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see regsvr32 writing the keys.

Comment: Maybe you just need to specify what keys you are looking for and what ATL/C++ code on the project makes you think those keys should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, even though my command prompt directory was the same as the one in which the DLL to be registered was located when I used the command- C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe DLLname.dll, it was registering the DLL located in System 32 folder.

Using absolute path for the DLL registered the correct DLL and new progID's appeared in HKCR.